# Authorize attribute on HomeController forces login on AllowAnonymous controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorize-attribute

The HomeController of my mvc 5 application has an [Authorize] attribute

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

The SimpleController is the followin (a simple test):

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class SimpleController : Controller
{
    // GET: Simple
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Why do I have to log in when I browse straight to http://url/simple/index?

I have to extra "force authentication code" or filters registered.

When I remove the [Authorize] on the HomeController, the SimpleController works fine, without the need to log in

Comment: The requirement of authorization on one controller has nothing to do with another. However, `[AllowAnonymous]` is only needed if you've also added `[Authorize]`. If the controller or action does not require authentication, remove the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute.

Comment: I know, but the strange thing is that  when I remove the [Authorize] on the HomeController, the SimpleController works fine, without the need to log in.

Comment: Do you have any child actions in the `HomeController` that you're calling in views for `SimpleController`? All child actions should either not have `[Authorize]` or if they're in a controller decorated with `[Authorize]`, should be decorated with `[AllowAnonymous]`. No child actions ever should *require* authorization. It must always be optional.

Comment: no, the view of the simplecontroller, it is almost empty, just a h1 tag and a p tag to display some text

Comment: Nothing in the layout?

Comment: no, I also use a basic layout for this test controller, to exclude that the layout is the cause

Comment: Not sure what to tell you then. Controllers are completely separate. Unless you're somehow acting `HomeController` from `SimpleController` (child action, etc.), `HomeController` will never even be instantiated, let alone force it's requirement for authorization onto `SimpleController`. Something else is going on not covered in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have configured Global Authorization filter in FilterConfig.cs, located in App_Start folder

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
}
```